# How to verify the loading variable while testing the mockservice in angular5

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Creating the test case suite for my application, from my component calling the API service to get the data, While triggering the service call making the loading progress bar after the success data retrieve hiding the loading bar in my application.

Service call data check i am doing with mock class, but i am struggling to verify to validate the loading variable check in my spec file.

> My component spec file

```
class MockAttachementsService {
  public getAttachmentDetails(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({ name: "Govind" });
  }
}


describe('AttachmentsComponent', () => {
  let component: AttachmentsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AttachmentsComponent>;
  let attachementsService: AttachementsService;
  let result  = { name: "Govind" };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule, RouterModule, RouterTestingModule, BrowserModule, MatProgressBarModule, TableModule, MultiSelectModule, FormsModule, CalendarModule, DropdownModule, SpinnerModule, TooltipModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [AttachmentsComponent, DataTableComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: AttachementsService, useClass: MockAttachementsService }]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AttachmentsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    attachementsService = TestBed.get(AttachementsService);

  }));

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
    component = null;
});


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should List the Attachment', () => {
    spyOn(attachementsService, 'getAttachmentDetails').and.callThrough();
    expect(component.loading).toBe(true);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.loading).toBe(false);
  });

});
```

After triggering the service call loading should be true after observable result return loading should be false, always loading is false only.

How can I validate this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using `MockAttachementsService` in the providers and it returns the `Observable` for your test and the `callThrough()` would also be using this service. I'm not sure when the `component.loading` is set to true as the component definition is not in the question, but you can do something like this to test, the functionality when loading is true.

```
describe('When the component is loading', () => {
    let nativeElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
      component.loading = true;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      nativeElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    });

    //e.g. test your spinner 
    it('the spinner should be displayed', () => {
      // replace with your expectation when loading is true.
      expect(nativeElement.querySelector('mat-spinner')).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });

  describe('When the component is not loading', () => {
    let nativeElement;
    beforeEach(() => {
      component.loading = false;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      nativeElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    });

    //e.g. test your spinner not to be there
    it('the spinner should not be displayed', () => {
      // replace with your expectation when loading is false.
      expect(nativeElement.querySelector('mat-spinner')).toBeFalsy();
    });
  });
```

Comment: service being called from my component ngOnInit so that I am not using the callThrough, though i can get the return value from the mockservice class.

Is that necessary to use callThrough?

Comment: What I meant is, the callThrough in the above test would do nothing, other than calling the method of MockAttachementsService. It is not going to actually call the method of AttachementsService, if are expecting that.